# backbone.fetch using "return" only returns undefined instead of the specific value

Tags: backbone.js

Hi i'm new to backbonejs,

I created a function to validate sessions and have if and else statements through my routes when calling this function

```
var validateSession = function(){
    var session = new sessionCollection();
    session.fetch( {
        success : function(){
            return true;
        },
        error : function(){
            CarRentalApp.trigger('admin:login');
            return false;
        }
    } );
};
```

the problem is the "return" statement is not working out for me. Instead of returning true or false, it returns undefined instead. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `$.Deferred()`

```
var validateSession = function(){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var session = new sessionCollection();
    session.fetch( {
        success : function(){
            defer.resolve(true);
        },
        error : function(){
            defer.resolve(false);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise();
};
```

And then:

```
$.when(validateSession()).done(function(result){
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I also used this solution as stated in the comments

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a javascript question rather than backbone.
Backbone.Collection.fetch method is an asynchronous method, that means if you do this:

```
validateSession();
```

the function will call session.fetch() and then return immediately, it won't wait the fetch() method finish it's job. you don't have return statement in the validateSession function, so it just return you undefined. and when the fetch() method finished, you won't get any notification.

if you want get the result of session.fetch(), I think you'd better trigger events in both cases of success and error:

```
var validateSession = function(){
    var session = new sessionCollection();
    session.fetch( {
        success : function(){
            CarRentalApp.trigger('valid:true');
        },
        error : function(){
            CarRentalApp.trigger('valid:false');
        }
    } );
};
```

then listen on these two events and do some process respectively.

hope this can help.

Comment: This is correct... there's two separate timelines going on. If you stepped through this with a debugger, you'd hit `fetch` and then proceed to the next statement after fetch. (Or in this case, exit the function.) To step through the `success` function, you'd need to set a separate breakpoint there.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this implementation earlier and it worked out well for me. The other solution that I tried was to use deferred after fetching and then return defer.promise() which also works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, even simpler, you can do what you want inside the success and error call back -- in case you don't need to refer outer variable.